# How to achieve multi-layered drawing with OpenGL ES on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiview, paint

I wanted to very quickly to make a simple drawing app for iOS, but I can't quite get the drawing to work - well, to save the content on each layer and restore the layers. It appears like all layers save the same pixels..

The idea was to have three layers and use OpenGL ES to draw on each layer. With no experience in the matter, I just tiled three UIViews and added a OpenGL drawing canvas to each UIView (a modified version of the PaintingView from the tutorial). When the user swapped drawing layer, I simply disabled user interaction on the other layers.

With this approach I experience a lot of oddities that I assume stems from my approach. So now, I think that I should somehow make three full screen buffers in the same PaintingView and just have OpenGL switch between them.

Am I on to something? Have anyone an approach that works?

Anything on-topic might help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need three layers?

Comment: Why not look into the coreGraphic framework? its well documented by apple and should do what you want.

Comment: I'm with @geminiCoder--I think OGL will be more work than using Core Animation layers + Core Graphics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make two different framebuffers: one for drawing to screen and second for drawing to texture.
Then, you can make 3 different textures, they will be your layers. Draw to them.
Finally, you can draw the textures you have to the first framebuffer and present in on screen.

Your draw cycle will be smth like this:

- bind RenderToTextureFramebuffer
- attach texture1 to RenderToTextureFramebuffer
- draw what you want in layer 1
- attach texture2 to RenderToTextureFramebuffer
- draw what you want in layer 2
- attach texture3 to RenderToTextureFramebuffer
- draw what you want in layer 3
- bind RenderToScreenFramebuffer
- bind texture1
- draw texture1 (your layer1)
- bind texture2
- draw texture2 (your layer2)
- bind texture3
- draw texture3 (your layer3)
- present final picture on screen

Comment: I followed the above procedure. The problem that I am getting is that I have to keep redrawing the layers to the screen at each frame by calling glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT), followed by drawing to screen. This results in a flickering effect. I am doing something wrong or is this to be expected?

Comment: Amendale, redrawing screen each frame and calling glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) before drawing is OK and shouldn't lead to flickering. Maybe something wrong with your buffers. Probably you should start another question and post your code there so people could understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

to have all functionality of painters - undo/redo and so on
IMHO you need to have just several arrays of graphic objects and iterate through them on every render pass.

Comment: He may separate logical part from graphics and keep history of operations, and redraw scene based on current logic state.