# Rendering "layers" in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, layer, framebuffer

I'm making an iOS app and I want to be able to render with individual "layers" so that I can do blending between them and use shaders on each individually before blending them all together and rendering to the screen.

I understand that I will be rendering to Textures and then rendering these textures on top of each other in the framebuffer, but I am not understanding clearly what code needs to be written to follow this procedure. In another answer I found what I want to do, but I don't know what code accomplishes this task: [How to achieve multi-layered drawing with OpenGL ES on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901721/how-to-achieve-multi-layered-drawing-with-opengl-es-on-ios) (For example how do I "Bind texture 1, then draw it"? What does it mean to "Attach texture 1"?)

I've also looked at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) regarding this technique but it isn't very clear about the steps or code for the actual rendering part of the process.

How would I go about doing this? (hopefully with code examples of each step because I haven't understood spotty instructions that expect me to just know what is needed for each step)

[Here is an example of what I want to do with this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLkIr.jpg) The spheres would be rendered into a "layer" or Texture2D which I would then pass through the shader, then render on top of a already partially rendered scene. I don't know exactly what kind of openGL code could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at wrong place. To use OpenGL, you need to study OpenGL, not anything else. Apple doesn't provide any OpenGL documentation because it's an open standard, so the specs are freely published. Apple assumes you're already familiar with it.

- [OpenGL ES 2.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf)
- [manual pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/)

I think you are having trouble because you don't have understanding of GL specific terms. The spec describes them very well and clearly. So, please read the spec. That will save your time A LOT. Or you will keep the trouble.

Also, I like to introduce a site which has very nice conceptual description of OpenGL pipeline.

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/

This site is targeting desktop GL, and some API may be different a little. Please focus on conceptual understanding. For example, here's an illustration from the site.

For more tutorials, google with proper keyword like `OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorials` (or how-tos). Here's [an example link](http://www.200monkeys.com/index.php/2012/12/28/opengl-es-2-0-tutorial-getting-started/), and would be helpful. There're also many more tutorials. If spec is too boring, it's also good to have some fun with tutors.

### Update

I like to say one more. IMO, the OpenGL is all about **drawing triangles**. Everything is ultimately converted into triangles in 3D space to represent some shape. Anything else all exists only for optimization. And in most cases, GL chooses *batch processing* for major optimization strategy. Because overhead of each drawing call is not affordable for most games.

It's hard to start OpenGL ES because it's an optimized version of desktop GL, so all *convenient or easy* drawing features are stripped off. This is same even on recent version of desktop GL.

So there's no such `drawOneTriangle` function. Instead GL has something like

1. make a buffer,
2. put list of many triangles there
3. select the buffer for next drawing.
4. draw all triangles in current buffer at once
5. delete the buffer.

By using buffer, you don't need to dispatch duplicated data to GPU from CPU. And GL uses this approach everywhere. For example, you don't have such `drawOneTriangleWithTexture` function to use textures. Instead, you have to

1. make a buffer
2. put list of many pixels there (bitmap)
3. select the buffer for next drawing.
4. draw all triangles with the texture pixel data in current buffers.
5. delete the buffer.

Everything overly complex stuffs on GL are all exists for optimization. This may look weird at first, but there're usually very good reasons for the design.

### Update 2

Now I think you're looking for *render to texture* feature. (well actually you already mentioned this…)

You can use a rendered image as a texture source. To do this,

1. you need to bind a frame-buffer with texture object rather then render-buffer object using some functions like `glFramebufferTexture`.
2. Once you render to a texture, and switch frame-buffer to final buffer, and bind the texture you drawn and others, and perform the final drawing. You need two frame buffers: one for render-to-texture, and one for final output.

Comment: And I am doing just that. There doesn't appear to be any place that clearly explains exactly what OpenGL does, nor clearly explains the purpose of buffers, or how they work, or to what the draw function draws, etc. etc... I'm tired of code not having clear explanations. That's all I ask here, but thank you, I am following your approach until now, but I would still appreciate a good and clear explanation of this method and the code behind it's steps.

Comment: @Danegraphics Don't be frustrated. Because object concepts in graphics API in both of OpenGL and DirectX are very complex because they're developed over decades. And people usually take years of time to be familiar with them.

Comment: I've already got the basics. It's the advanced stuff that I need to move onto now, and there are so few clear resources. I'm looking at [this tutorial](http://blog.db-in.com/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-2/#primitives) especially the part about offscreen rendering, and I googled "Render to texture opengl" and now I know how to render to a texture, but not how to render a texture on top of another (or other magical things, like using the texture as if it were an image), so I'll have to go piece that together. It's a slow thing having to build your own code out of scraps of the internet.

Comment: [Another thing I'm looking at](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples)

Comment: @Danegraphics Do you mean something like *alpha blending*?

Comment: No. Alpha blending, rotation, animation, and simple stuff like that I've already got. I mean that there are some visual effects that require me to render many images into one layer, then pass a shader only on the sum of those rendered images to make a new image, then render that image on top of the rest.

Comment: I see you updated your response. This I know and understand. It's smart that way, but I need a way to do what I've described above, which can't be done in a batch. For example, say I wanted to create the following morphing blob effect: http://i.imgur.com/lGx8CHW.jpg

Comment: @Danegraphics I updated it again. I hope this helps.